# Stripe subscription webhooks missing metadata and client_reference_id

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm having issues linking stripe webhooks to customers, since I generally use the client_reference_id or metadata field, however subscription webhooks seem to not have these fields. For example the event *checkout.session.completed* does contain the client_reference_id, whereas *invoice.paid* does not.

**NodeJS code to generate payment:**

```
        const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
            payment_method_types: ['card'],
            line_items: [
            {
                price_data: {
                    currency: 'usd',
                    product_data: {
                        name: `Premium license`,
                    },
                    unit_amount: 600,
                    recurring: {
                        interval: "month",
                        interval_count: 1
                    },
                },
                quantity: 1
            }],
            subscription_data: {
                trial_period_days: 1,
            },
            metadata: { 'userId': userId },
            client_reference_id: userId,
            mode: 'subscription',
            customer_email: customerEmail,
            success_url: `...`,
            cancel_url: `...`,
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`client_reference_id`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-client_reference_id) is a property of Checkout Session objects in Stripe, but not any other Stripe objects.

Subscription events (like `customer.subscription.created`) describe Subscription objects, and Invoice events (like `invoice.paid`) describe Invoices, neither of which are Checkout Sessions, so the property is missing.

Typically the way all of this is linked together is with the Customer object (`cus_123`) in Stripe, which should be present on all of the events mentioned in the `customer` property.  [Checkout will create the Customer object for you if you don't specify an existing one.](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-customer)

Comment: But we still need to add some metadata in the customer to have access to the user id right?

Comment: Yes, if you want to store arbitrary information (like the user ID from your system) you can use [metadata](https://stripe.com/docs/api/metadata), which can be set on many Stripe objects.

Comment: I don't see how an authenticated user's ID in a system is arbitrary to the end-to-end events involved in checkout. If a session uniquely involves a single checkout, why wouldn't subsequent events generated due to that session not carry along this crucial information? This seems like a stripe business decision to make developers lean toward using stripe customer objects as keys, unnecessarily enmeshing systems with Stripe.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's a major missing that there is no option to link between events. This becomes critical when you can't rely on the order of webhook events.

I did work around this using `metadata` though. Pass your own reference id, say, `my_database_reference_id` to the metadata of both `checkout.session.create` and also in the `subscription_data` in checkout creation. This can be the same value you pass inside `client_reference_id`. Now you can use this while listening to webhook, to connect between the checkout session and subscription object, irrespective of the order it comes in.

NB: Please be warned that metadata can be edited by the Stripe Account, so please be careful if you are a platform and relying on this for any logic.

Comment: Thanks, subscription_data.metadata is exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: Do you have a reference for stripe editing metadata? In some scenarios such as Fraud detection, It reads the metadata but doesn't edit it.

Comment: thanks a lot! spent half the day figuring out why the webhook is missing metadata